# A woman with two children came. Is "with two children" an attribute or an adverbial modifier?

Tags: attributive-nouns, adverbials

I'm not sure what the phrase “with two children” is doing here. Is it describing "a woman" or "came" or this make sense both way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English the word order is relatively inflexible, so a modifying phrase normally immediately follows the head. The sentence does not imply that she came with the two children, but it does imply that the children are hers. In many other languages the equivalent sentence would be ambiguous, though.